# Is there a way in squish to use plural and singular in same BDD step?

Tags: bdd, squish

I am trying to implement a BDD step which can be use if the step is referring to singular or plural ex:
**Then I should see the name "John" is displayed**
but also I want to use the same step if I have more then one name
**Then I should see the names "John, George" are displayed**

In java you can do this when you implement the step like this:
@Step("Then I should see the name? (regex) (:?is|are) displayed")

?- is for the plural
and(:? | ) is when you want to replace a word

In feature file when you type (names or name; is or are) it points to the same step

Is there a way to do this in squish?

Comment: You can use regular expressions in step names, as described at [Using Step Patterns with Regular Expressions](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/api.bdt.functions.html#api.bdt.functions.regexpplaceholders). Are you certain that this is a relevant problem for your users? What problem do you see with 'Then the name(s) "..." should be displayed'?

Comment: This is relevant because in this way you can reuse a step more often, and also is important to write correct from grammatically  point of view.  If you can write a step  which can be use in more then one situation I think you gain a lot of flexibility.  In the book "The Cucumber Book" (https://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) is described how to better write  the steps.

Comment: Yes, but what about the example that I provided? It tackles the problem without much of a compromise, while at the same time keeping it simple.

Comment: The example with regex expression can be use as workaround of the problem. In general when you use a regex you want to pass something as a variable and to be use in the method, but I am talking about writing steps in order to be grammatically correct and not use regex which normally is used for passing variables, please see this posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528064/using-proper-grammar-in-gherkin

Comment: My example was not about regular expressions. Here is my example again: 'Then the name(s) "..." should be displayed'

Comment: The power of this feature is that you can write just one implemetation for this steps: "Then The results are ..."  and "Then the result is..." and in feature file you don't have to write "Then the result(s) is(are)" which is not a clean way to write steps. For more examples you can look at this link:  https://agileforall.com/just-enough-regular-expressions-for-cucumber/   on row:
 I might write something like this:

[When(@"^(I'm logged|I log) in as an? (.*)$")]
public void LogInAs(string role)
{
// log in as the given role
};

Comment: For the example provided from the link above in feature file you write "When I'm logged in as an ..." or "When I log in as an..."  and this is a clean way to write tests.

Answer (score 1):

See [Using Step Patterns with Regular Expressions](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/api.bdt.functions.html#api.bdt.functions.regexpplaceholders) in the [froglogic Squish manual](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/) for using regular expressions in BDD steps.

Based on that, the following works for me:

```
# Use (?:...) because it is non-capturing
# Also see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
@Then("I should see the (?:name|names) \"(.*)\" (?:is|are) displayed", regexp=True)
def step(context, nameOrNamesCommaSeparated):
    """Examples:
        Then I should see the name "John" is displayed
        Then I should see the names "John, George" are displayed
    """

    names = []
    if "," in nameOrNamesCommaSeparated:
        names = nameOrNamesCommaSeparated.split(",")
        for i, n in enumerate(names):
            names[i] = n.strip()
    else:
        names = [nameOrNamesCommaSeparated]

    for i, n in enumerate(names):
        test.log("Name #%s: %s" % (i, n))
```

Comment: Indeed the provided answer is working for me as well

Comment: My reputation for the moment in below 15, and  I cannot vote

Comment: You can replace `(?:name|names)` by `name(s)` and `(?:is|are)` by `is/are` according to doc : https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions#optional-text

Comment: @MaximeP, I believe in Squish the regular expression functionality of the used scripting language is being used. I cannot tell if your suggested variants address the "non-capturing" aspect.